# Alternative Populist Badge Description

Tags: discussion, badge-description

I find the populist badge description a little confusing. However, if I understand it correctly, but it be better for the description to say this instead(Thanks to Kate Gregory):

> Highest scoring answer, with score more than double the accepted
>   answer, on a question where the accepted answer score is more than 10.

Instead of:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of
>   more than 10 by more than 2x

EDITED ALTERNATIVE DESCRIPTION.

Comment: I don't understand what was confusing about it, but I edited it and addressed your issue.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer must have a score _greater than 10_, i.e. at least 11. And your answer must have _more than twice the score of the accepted answer_, so you need at least a score of 23 to get the badge.

Comment: For populist you need a minimum of 23 votes on your answer. More if the accepted answer is higher than 11. "More than 10" is not "a minimum of 10" and the "more than" applies to the accepted answer, not yours. So your rewrite isn't right yet. You are, however, doing a great job of proving that the current text is confusing.

Comment: Edited with a better description...

Comment: Highest scoring answer, with score more than double the accepted answer, on a question where the accepted answer score is more than 10.

Comment: @Kate Gregory that is pretty good! I will add it to the original post.

Comment: @KateGregory make that an answer :)